# YouTube with accent?

Tags: youtube, accent-sensitive

This maybe a dumb question but I have a problem with YouTube.

I live in Barcelona and I live in a shared house. My roommates are Indian and most of the time they watch Indian movies or other programs on YouTube.

I started to learn Android programming and I obviously there is no better place than YouTube to find tutorials.
So the problem is, although I use my own laptop and my own Google account to watch the videos and tutorials, it always shows me videos with Indian accent (for sure Indians are not the only ones preparing tutorials, right?).
I don't want to say that the videos or tutorials are bad, but to be honest sometimes it is hard to understand (I know I'm not perfect English speaker, I'm not a native English speaker either, I have problem with pronunciation), also, isn't it weired that YouTube (or better to say Google) even tracks your WiFi network, or is it just me.
I thought it personalizes according to your account and videos you have watched before, but it seems that it also tracks your WiFi network.

So anyway, if this a known issue and if there is any solution for this I'll be more than happy to know.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, accent cannot be detected but the account names can be, so they can be user-spesific. I recommend maybe you quit from your account and search using the default youtube browser to see if anything changes. If not, there's no such filtering. Just those people make more tutorials than native speakers.